# Deploy OVA as VM in Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We deploy virtualised PBXs from various manufacturers in the cloud.
One PBX I would like to move our new deployments from the current platform to Google Cloud.

We currently use GCP Compute VMs for PBX from a different manufacturer and these work well.

The one I want to move only is only supported if deployed as an OVA image. The underlying OS is CentOS 6 so should be OK for GCP

I have tried everything I can find from the documentation to deploy an OVA but none are successful. Using the command line SDK Shell looks promising and then fails with a few ERRORs.

Does anyone have any simplified instrauctions to complete this? I have found nothing to indicate the software is not conpatible with GCP.

many thanks!

EDIT

I should add that the above does create an image but will not boot.
Creating a custome image by using an OVA uploaded to a Bucket creates a bootable machine but nothing related to the OVA! It boots a Debian machine and not the CentOS machine I would be expecting

Answer (score 0):

Google compute engine currently doesn't support exporting VMs in OVF or OVA format. As per [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/compute#iaas_comparison) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285638/vm-instance-is-not-accessible-the-project-you-requested-is-unavailable) Compute engine support only RAW format. You may want to try [converting OVA file](http://opentox.github.io/installation/2012/08/02/converting-ova-images-to-kvm) into RAW format using some free tools like VirtualBox or extracting files in RAW format.